# Função para multiplicar cada linha de uma matriz pelo valor de sua diagonal secundaria correspondente

Tags: c, funções, matriz, array-multidimensional

Não estou conseguindo pegar os valores da diagonal secundaria de uma matriz por uma função.

```
/*
19) Elabore uma sub-rotina que receba como parâmetro uma matriz A(6,6) e multiplique cada linha pelo
elemento da diagonal principal da linha. A sub-rotina deverá retornar a matriz alterada para ser mos-
trada no programa principal.
 */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define DIM 6

//Funções
void Prencher_Matriz(int mat[][DIM]);
void Imprimir_Matriz(int mat[][DIM]);

void Armazenar_Diagonal_Secundaria(int mat[][DIM]);
void MultiplicacaoPelaDiagPrincipal(int mat[][DIM]);

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int i, j;
    int matriz[DIM][DIM];

    Prencher_Matriz(&matriz);
    Imprimir_Matriz(&matriz);
    Armazenar_Diagonal_Secundaria(&matriz);

    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

void Prencher_Matriz(int mat[][DIM]) {
    int i, j;
    srand(time(NULL));

    for (i = 0; i < DIM; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < DIM; j++) {
            mat[i][j] = (rand() % 10) + 1;
        }
    }
}

void Imprimir_Matriz(int mat[][DIM]) {
    int i, j;

    printf("MATRIZ GERADA \n");
    for (i = 0; i < DIM; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < DIM; j++) {
            printf("%4d", mat[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

void Armazenar_Diagonal_Secundaria(int mat[][DIM]) {
    int i, j, p = 0;
    int ElementosDS[DIM];

    for (i = 0; i < DIM; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < DIM; j++) {
            if (i + j == DIM - 1) {
                ElementosDS[p] = mat[DIM - i];
                p++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Bom, o que eu entendi o que é pra fazer é armazenar os valores dos elementos da diagonal principal em um vetor e multiplica-lo todas de sua linha por ele. Segue um exemplo:

| 1 | 2 | 3 |

| 4 | 5 | 6 |

| 7 | 8 | 9 |

Os elementos da diagonal principal da matriz acima são matriz é 1, 5 e 9. Segundo o que foi pedido a matriz gerada seria:

| 1  | 2  | 3  |

| 20 | 25 | 30 |

| 63 | 72 | 81 |

Eu não estou conseguindo passar a matriz para dentro das funções. Quero fazer uma função para armazenar os elementos da digonal em um vetor e em seguida pegar este mesmo vetor gerado nessa função e joga-lo em outra função para fazer os cálculos em cima da matriz original.

Comment: Você no titulo diz que é para multiplicar pelo elemento da diagonal secundária, mas no comentário do código diz que é pela diagonal principal. Qual diagonal é para multiplicar afinal ?

Comment: Além do que o @Isac disse, o que quer dizer com "multiplicar cada linha"?
Você quer multiplicar a soma dos elementos de cada linha pela diagona?Isso não vai retornar uma matriz(6,6). Ou então você quer imprimir cada elemento de uma linha pela diagonal?

Comment: Acabei me confundindo, é a diagonal principal mesmo.

Comment: Pelo que entendi é para pegar o elemento daquela diagonal e multiplicar por todos da daquela linha. Ex: